# Копирование структуры и данных одной таблицы в другую

Tags: c#

Всем привет, возник вопрос при копировании таблицы из БД сервера в таблицу локальной БД.
Клиент-серверное приложение.

```
//Адаптер для таблицы БД сервера
private RateOfExchangeTableAdapter STA =
            new RateOfExchangeTableAdapter();

//DataSet для таблицы БД сервера
private ServDataBase SDT = new ServDataBase();

//Адаптер для таблицы локальной БД
private LocalRateOfExchangeTableAdapter LTA =
             new LocalRateOfExchangeTableAdapter();

//DataSet для таблицы локальной БД
private LocalDataBaseDataSet LDT =
            new LocalDataBaseDataSet();

//System.Data.DataSet           
DataTable LDS = new DataTable();

//DataView для таблицы БД сервера

public DataView RateOfExchangeDataView
        {
            get
            {
                return SDT.RateOfExchange.DefaultView;
            }
        }

//DataView для таблицы локальной БД

public DataView LocalRateOfExchangeDataView
    {
        get
        {
            return LDT.LocalRateOfExchange.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

Но попытка сохранить данные следующим образом оканчивается неудачно:

```
    private void CopyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Копирую структуру и данные в System.Data.DataSet 
       //(делаю снимок загруженной таблицы БД сервера)
        LDS = SDT.RateOfExchange.Copy();

        //Объединяю одну таблицу с другой
        LDT.LocalRateOfExchange.Merge(LDS);

        //Пытаюсь заполнить локальную таблицу данными из LDT, но она оказывается пуста
        LTA.Fill(LDT.LocalRateOfExchange);

        this.DataContext = this;

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить данную неудачу. В чем ошибка такого подхода к копированию?
Надеюсь, ответ на вопрос будет полезен многим людям, которым придется заниматься подобными вещами.
Заранее спасибо! Если нужно что-то подробнее расписать - дайте знать.

Answer (score 1):

Привидите описание таблиц RateOfExchange и LocalRateOfExchange. Может быть у вас не совпадают структуры (порядок, наименование и типы данных столбцов) этих таблиц, т.к. насколько я понял у вас используются разные классы-наследники DataTable для каждой из них.

Ваш проект отлично работает. Для проверки модифицируейте метод SaveDataInLocalFromServ_Click так:

```
private void SaveDataInLocalFromServ_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            SDT.MeltingResult.AddMeltingResultRow(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

            //При нажатии на данную кнопку копирую структуру и данные таблицы сервера
            LDS = SDT.MeltingResult.Copy();

            //и объединяю ее с пустой таблицей
            LDT.LocalMeltingResult.Merge(LDS);
        }
```

Поставте точку останова на конец метода - на строку где закрывающая фигурная скобка. В окне watch посмотрите значения выражений:

```
LDS
SDT.MeltingResult
LDT.LocalMeltingResult
```

Вы увидите что фиктивная строка добавилась и в LDS и в LDT.LocalMeltingResult.
Чтобы сохранить локальный датасет в локальную базу достаточно команды:

```
STA.Fill(SDT.MeltingResult);
```

При ее выполнении фиктивная строка успешно попадает в локальную базу. Таким образом, процедура копирования работает успешно.

Поправка: чтобы сохранить локальный датасет нужно выполнить команду:

```
LTA.Update(LDT.LocalMeltingResult);
```

чтобы загрузить:

```
LTA.Fill(LDT.LocalMeltingResult);
```

**UDP**

метод SaveIntoLocalDataBaseButton_Click работает  правильно и остался без изменений:

```
private void SaveIntoLocalDataBaseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //При нажатии на кнопку происходит сохранение любых 
            //модификаций в таблице при условии если они возможны

            //По аналогии с таблицей сервера
            LTA.Update(LDT.LocalMeltingResult);
        }
```

но я изменил метод LoadFromLocaDataBaseButton_Click так:

```
private void LoadFromLocaDataBaseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            LTA.Fill(LDT.LocalMeltingResult);

            DataContext = this;
        }
```

возможно из-за отсутсвия команды 
LTA.Fill(LDT.LocalMeltingResult);
данные не загружались в грид, и вы их не видели, но на самом деле они были

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, используются два разных класса-наследника, так как методы Fill и Update, которые вызываются с помощью адаптеров таблиц принимают в качестве параметров только "родные" типы. Порядок, наименование и типы данных столбцов аналогичны. Вопрос, к сожалению, не получается решить уже неделю. Уважаемый, UserTest, не смогли бы вы помотреть мой проект в Visual Studio? Это простое тестовое WPF приложение, которое работает с БД. Отдельно с каждой БД работать научился, но загрузить данные из одной таблицы в другую не могу.

Comment: давайте проект, в полной картине легче ориентироваться

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29445438/WPFDataBinding.rar.
Добавил подробные комментарии на каждом шаге, думаю картина будет ясна.

Comment: Программа все равно работает не так как хотелось бы. При нажатии на кнопку данные копируются в датагрид локальной таблицы, но их нельзя сохранить физически в локальной БД. Это можно как то исправить? Грубо говоря после того как мы загрузили данные в локальный датагрид - можно ли эти данные физически сохранить в локальной таблице? Посмотрите пожалуйста метод SaveIntoLocalDataBaseButton_Click и если не сложно - исправьте, я просто уже запутался..

Comment: добавил коды методов в ответ

Comment: Вопрос остается открытым, я сделал скриншоты и попробовал объяснить проблему более детально, посмотрите пожалуйста документ http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29445438/MyProblem.pdf

Comment: убедитесь что вы смотрите таблицу правильного sdf-файла, путь к нему должен быть таким "WPFDataBinding\WPFDataBinding\bin\Debug\LocalDataBase.sdf", а не "WPFDataBinding\WPFDataBinding\LocalDataBase.sdf". Т.к. база, содержащая данные сохраненные при отладке, лежит в папке debug, а не в корне проекта. В моем sdf-файле имеется та фиктивная строчка, которую я добавлял в ServDataBase для проверки